# Meaning of the derivative $\frac{d f(x,y)}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose we are given a function $f(x,y) = x^2 + y$ defined over $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = 2x + \frac{dy}{dx}$$ and $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x$$

**How do I interpret $\frac{df}{dx}$, both mathematically and intuitively?**

We know derivatives refer to tangents and in the case of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, we fix the $y$ and look at the tangent of the now-single-variable function $g(x) = f(x,y_0)$. I don't know what it means in the case of $\frac{df}{dx}$.

Comment: $y$ is another function of $x$. You are intuitively trying to see how $g(x) := f(x,y(x))$ is changing.

Comment: The symbol $\frac{df}{dx}$ doesn't make sense for multivariable functions(maybe I don't know this notation). Can you please explain where did you find it?

Comment: @Harry it is a total derivative https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two derivatives you provided in your question will coincide as there is no relation between $x$ and $y$. However, if one depends on the other (or let's say that they both depend on $t$) then the situation is different.

For example, if instead you had:
$$f(t)=x(t)^2+y(t)$$
then
$$\frac{df(t)}{dt}=2x(t)\frac{dx(t)}{dt}+\frac{dy(t)}{dt}$$

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "coincide"? What's $\frac{dy}{dx}$ when they "coincide"?

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ do not depend on each other then the partial and the total derivative are the same.  See the examples there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#The_chain_rule_for_total_derivatives

Answer (score 3):

Things depend a lot on whether $y$ is ultimately a function of $x$.

## If $y$ is a function of $x$...

### Scenario

In this kind of case, we might have a physical situation in mind.
For example, suppose we have a conical tank that has some amount of
water in it. Then the volume of water is given by the volume formula
for all cones: $V_{1}(h,r)=\dfrac{1}{3}\pi r^{2}h$. But the shape
of the tank forces a ratio between $h$ and $r$, say $r=\dfrac{h}{2}$.
So there's another function that gives the volume of the water in
terms of just the height: $V_{2}\left(h\right)=V_{1}\left(h,\dfrac{h}{2}\right)=\dfrac{1}{3}\pi\left(\dfrac{h}{2}\right)^{2}h=\dfrac{\pi}{12}h^{3}$.

In this scenario, $\dfrac{\partial V_{1}\left(h,r\right)}{\partial h}=\dfrac{1}{3}\pi r^{2}$.
And in the case of our tank, this could be written as $\dfrac{1}{3}\pi\left(\dfrac{h}{2}\right)^{2}=\dfrac{\pi}{12}h^{2}$.
And we also have $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V_{2}\left(h\right)}{\mathrm{d}h}=\dfrac{\pi}{4}h^{2}$.
By the chain rule, these are related as
$$
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V_{2}\left(h\right)}{\mathrm{d}h}=\left.\left(\dfrac{\partial V_{1}\left(h,r\right)}{\partial h}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}h}{\mathrm{d}h}+\dfrac{\partial V_{1}\left(h,r\right)}{\partial r}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}h}\right)\right|_{r=h/2}
$$

$$
=\left.\left(\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\pi r^{2}\right)\left(1\right)+\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\pi rh\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\right)\right|_{r=h/2}
$$

$$
=\left(\dfrac{1}{12}\pi h^{2}\right)\left(1\right)+\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\pi h^{2}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)
$$

$$
=\dfrac{\pi}{4}h^{2}\checkmark
$$

### Meaning

But what does this mean?

$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V_{2}\left(h\right)}{\mathrm{d}h}=\dfrac{\pi}{4}h^{2}$
means that as you increase the height of the water $h$ by a tiny
amount $\Delta h$, the volume of the water in the tank would increase
by about $\dfrac{\pi}{4}h^{2}\Delta h$.

And $\dfrac{\partial V_{1}\left(h,r\right)}{\partial h}=\dfrac{1}{3}\pi r^{2}$
means that if you increased the height of a cone by $\Delta h$ but
did {*}not{*} change the radius accordingly (so that the shape of
your new theoretical cone no longer matches that of the tank), then
the volume would increase by about $\dfrac{1}{3}\pi r^{2}\Delta h$.

The chain rule calculation above breaks down the water's volume increase
into two parts: the $\dfrac{\partial V_{1}\left(h,r\right)}{\partial h}$
part that's due to the height increase alone, and the other part of
the increase that's due to the naturally-increasing radius ( $\dfrac{\partial V_{1}\left(h,r\right)}{\partial r}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}h}$).

Now, all that said, it's relatively common (especially in science?)
to denote $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ by the same symbol, like $V$, since
they both represent the volume. Then we might say something like "$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}h}$
is the rate of the entire change in the water's volume as height changes
and $\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial h}$ is the change due to the height
change alone."

### Graphically

We can think about both of these values graphically, forgetting about
the tank situation entirely.

Firstly, consider $\left.\dfrac{\partial V_{1}\left(h,r\right)}{\partial h}\right|_{\left(h,r\right)=\left(2,1\right)}$.
This means we take the graph of $V_{1}$ in 3D, slice it with the
plane $r=1$ (since the partial derivative with respect to $h$ should
keep $r$ constant), and then look at the slope of the intersection
at the point with $h=2$, to get $\dfrac{1}{3}\pi\left(1\right)^{2}=\dfrac{\pi}{3}\approx1$.

See the situation in this graph:

[image: the graph of v 1 and the plane to show the partial derivative]

Now, $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V_{2}\left(h\right)}{\mathrm{d}h}$ involves
$V_{2}\left(h\right)=V_{1}\left(h,\dfrac{h}{2}\right)$. So we should
slice the graph of $V_{1}$ with $r=\dfrac{h}{2}$. Then, because
we want the change with respect to $h$, we shouldn't look at the
slope in that plane (that would be a sort of [directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) of $V_{1}$ with value $\dfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt{5}}\approx2.8<3$),
but rather the slope of the projection onto the $hv$-coordinate plane
(corresponding to the function $V_{2}$).

Here's the situation in 3D:

[image: The diagonal plane and V 1 at an angle to show the plane isn't parallel to a coordinate plane]

Here's a viewing angle that suggests the projection and helps us see the slope $\dfrac{\pi}{4}\left(2\right)^{2}=\pi>3$

[image: The diagonal plane and V 1 and a viewpoint that suggests the projection]

We can compare the two values in the same picture with both planes
at once:

[image: both planes and the graph with the point highlighted]

## If $y$ is not a function of $x$...

Now, if $y$ is not considered a function of $x$ in any way (and
vice versa), then there is no function like $V_{2}$ to write and
no plane like $r=h/2$ to cut with. In a normal mathematical way of
writing things, all we have is $\mathrm{d}f=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\mathrm{d}x+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\mathrm{d}y$.
(Assuming $f$ is differentiable) this basically means that if we
increase $x$ by a tiny amount $\Delta x$ and increase $y$ by a
tiny amount $\Delta y$, then $f$ will increase by approximately
$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Delta x+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Delta y$,
so we might write $\Delta f\approx\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Delta x+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Delta y$.

We could divide that equation by $\Delta x$ if it's not zero, to
get $\dfrac{\Delta f}{\Delta x}\approx\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Delta y}{\Delta x}$,
meaning something like "the relative increase of $f$ compared to
the increase in $x$ is approximated by the sum of (a fixed term for
how much change in $x$ alone affects $f$) and (a relative term based
on any change in $y$)".

Now, this is probably not common in this context, but I suppose we
could symbolically divide everything in the original equation by $\mathrm{d}x$
to write $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$
to represent the above approximate equation in a notation with differentials.
This is not useless, as we could then apply various dependencies of
$y$ on $x$ (e.g. various shapes of conical tank) to this equation
directly; we would then be treating the $f$ on the left like $V_{2}$
and the $f$s on the right like $V_{1}$.

Comment: Wow, I can't thank you enough! Would you mind telling me how you created these graphs? :)

Comment: @fractalletter Happy to help. If you feel it addressed your question better than the other answer, consider accepting it. I created the graphs in Mathematica. If you know the desired view angle/vector it's possible to export the same image files with the Free Wolfram Engine for Developers. But Geogebra and math3d.org are also free and have much more accessible interfaces for making 3D graphs

Comment: I didn't know of math3d.org (the other two I did). Interestingly math3d supports the $z$ coordinate as a variable (like $z^2 = x+y$ or other implicit equations) which Geogebra 3D does not. I haven't checked it out completely; this was just my initial observation.

Comment: @fractalletter https://www.geogebra.org/m/tXmButvj makes it seem like Geogebra 3D should support implicit surfaces.